# Como converter uma string para esta codificação?

Tags: python, programação-estruturada

Estou tentando converter texto em uma linguagem binaria, porém continua saindo letras no resultado, gostaria que fosse criado um texto de acordo com a numeração que cada letra recebeu:

```
a = 10000
c = 10011
d = 10000
e = 10000
f = 10000
g = 10000
h = 10000
i = 10000
j = 10000
l = 10000
m = 10000
n = 10000
o = 10000
p = 10000
q = 10000
r = 10000
s = 10000
t = 10000
u = 10000
v = 10000
w = 10000
x = 10000
y = 10000
z = 10000

texto = input('DIGITE UM TEXTO: ')

tam = len(texto)

for i in range(tam):
    print('{}' .format(texto[i]))
```

Alguém pode me ajudar me apontando o erro?

Comment: A única letra com valor diferente é o *c*, isso não parece fazer sentido. Qual deveria ser o resultado?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

É bem simples na verdade, você pode seguir o exemplo do nosso amigo Daniel Reis.
Segue o código:

```
letter = {
    'a':'',
    'b':'',
    'c':'',
    'd':'',
    'e':'',
    'f':'',
    'g':'',
    'h':'',
    'i':'',
    'j':'',
    'k':'',
    'l':'',
    'm':'',
    'n':'',
    'o':'',
    'p':'',
    'q':'',
    'r':'',
    't':'',
    'u':'',
    'v':'',
    'x':'',
    'w':'',
    'y':'',
    'z':'',
    'r':'',
}

phrase = input('Entre com uma frase:')
text = ''

for i in phrase:
    text += letter[i]

print(text)
```

Basicamente no código você possui um dicionário, um dicionário nada mais é do que uma variável que atribui uma chave a determinado valor, mais utilizada em listas que não mudam os seus valores e não dependem de uma ordem para serem consultadas ou exibidas, basicamente como um dicionário mesmo.

No FOR, você estará percorrendo cada letra da frase que o usuário introduziu e incluindo na variável saída pelo valor correspondente a letra no dicionário, que seria a chave.

Abraços.

Comment: Muito obrigado.

Answer (score 0):

Ao invés de criar uma variável para cada letra do alfabeto, você deveria criar uma estrutura do tipo dicionário para converter as letras de uma codificação para outra. A iteração também deve ser modificada. O código ficaria mais ou menos assim:

```
alfabeto={'a':'1000','b':'1001','c':'1010'}

texto = input('DIGITE UM TEXTO: ')

saida=""

for letra in texto:
    saida=saida+alfabeto[letra]

print(saida)
```

Comment: Perfeito, não lembrava desta estrutura.